# Multiple entry in google calendar with same ics file

Tags: icalendar

I am trying to a event and send invite through ics file. I have create a ics file.My ics file is below.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:test@1324
DTSTART:20160518T144218
DTEND:20160518T154218
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Test
LOCATION:New Delhi
ORGANIZER:amankumar0511@gmail.com
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

on clicking it two times. It creates two entry in the calendar. It should update the existing entry.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: my question is if we use the same ics file. It should edit the previous event. But it is creating the event in the google calender.